# MinGW missing Active Movie headers?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw32

I'm trying to compile Qt 4.8.4 with an up-to-date installation of MinGW, and I seem to be missing some headers. I get through a lot of the compilation, but when it gets to the Phonon plugin, I get:

```
c:\mingw\include\dshow.h:30:21: fatal error: amaudio.h: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, amaudio.h is missing, as is amvideo.h, both of which are included in dshow.h (there may be other headers missing too, those were just the ones I noticed). Should these be included? dshow.h is in the w32api package in MinGW. It looks like amaudio.h and amvideo.h aren't among the installed files when I look at this package in MinGW Installation Manager.

Comment: possibly mingw doesn't have all the headers but mingw-w64 does...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you.
Try to download both include from here: http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/master/tree/include/

and after tell me if it worked.

Comment: No luck. Apparently amaudio.h includes dsound.h, which isn't among those headers. I found a copy of dsound.h in an old MinGW DirectX header package, but dshow.h also included strmif.h, which referred to a type IBaseFilter that wasn't declared in any of the MinGW headers. I suspect there were some include lines in an old version of dshow.h (and strmif.h) that got either uncommented or accidentally reinserted in the new one.

Comment: Try to link the headers' path in project properties. Close NetBeans and restart it. Should works then. Or download this mingw version: http://mamedev.org/tools/. Should contanis also directx headers modified specifically for mingw only. Also download Microsoft SDK: should contain DirectX headers. When you find them, copy and past all into mingw include directory.

Comment: I might just report this as a bug to the MinGW guys. I think I can live without Phonon.